# tableview custom cell button single selection/deselction

Tags: swift, tableview

i have been coding for a while i am stuck with tableview single selection/deselection. 
I have a tableview with custom cell which has a button. if i click on one button another button in bottom gets selected as well.For example when i click on button with index 2 another button gets click in the button.

it should be like when i click on one button other buttons should be deselected.

Thanks!

[image]

```
 func QuickReview( sender: UIButton){
    if cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.isSelected == true {
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.isSelected = false
    }
    else {
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.isSelected = true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells get reused. You need to ensure the exact same set of properties are set/reset in both conditions.

```
func QuickReview( sender: UIButton){
    if cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.isSelected {
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // or whatever
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal) // or whatever
    } else {
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black // or whatever
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // or whatever
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.layer.borderWidth = 3 // or whatever
        cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    }

    cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.isSelected = !cell.EventReviewQuickeReviewBtn.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you select any button then you should have mark `isSelected` property to false

assuming you have a list of models for your table view like

```
class Example{
...
var isSelected: Bool
...
}
```

(in ViewController)

```
let list: [Example] = [example1, example2, example3]


on tap of any button deselect all then selected desire button like

list.forEach { (example) in
                example.isSelected = false
            }
list[selectedButtonIndex].isSelected = true
```

and then reload your tableView.